# Finding the n-th root of unity in a finite field

Tags: finite-field

I'm trying to find the `n`-th root of unity in a finite field that is given to me. `n` is a power of 2. The finite field has prime order. I know that if this were just normal numbers, I could find it using $e^{(2\pi ik/n)}$. I have no idea how to translate that into finite fields.

Comment: But you are working in the multiplicative group, which has not prime order.  See also [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/58359)

Comment: @Ruggero: actually, there do exist finite fields with prime-sized multiplicative groups; for example, $GF(2^{127})$.

Comment: @Ruggero The group I'm working with is certainly prime order.

Comment: If the multiplicative group you're working in has prime order and `n` is a power of 2, then the answer is easy; either you're working in $GF(3)$ (and so the answer is 1 and 2), or you're working in a larger group, in which case the only `n`-th root of 1 is 1, that is $x^n = 1$ only if $x=1$

Comment: @poncho Ops. I confess my mind is often limited to prime fields.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In a finite field of size $q$, the multiplicative subgroup has order $q-1$ (i.e. all elements are invertible except $0$). If $n$ is relatively prime to $q-1$, then there is only one $n$-th root of unity, i.e. $1$ itself. If $n$ divides $q-1$, then there are $n$ roots of unity. In the remainder of this answer, I assume that you are in that case, i.e. $n$ divides $q-1$.

Everything I write below uses computations *in the finite field* (i.e. modulo $q$, if $q$ is prime).

To get an $n$-th root of unity, you generate a random non-zero $x$ in the field. Then:
$$ (x^{(q-1)/n})^n = x^{q-1} = 1 $$
Therefore, $x^{(q-1)/n}$ is an $n$-th root of unity. Note that you can end up with any of the $n$ $n$-th roots of unity (including $1$ itself), each with probability $1/n$.

Now you may want to have a *primitive* $n$-th root of unity, i.e. one value $g$ such that all $n$-th roots of unity can be obtained with values $g^j$ for integers $j$ ranging from $0$ to $n-1$. If $g$ is an $n$-th root of unity, then it is primitive if and only if $g^j \neq 1$ for any $j > 0$ that divides $n$, except $n$ itself. In your case this is easy: since $n$ is a power of $2$, any $j$ that divides $n$ is also a power of $2$. In practice, this yields the following:

- Get a random $x \neq 0$ in your finite field.
- Compute $g = x^{(q-1)/n}$.
- If $g^{n/2} \neq 1$, then $g$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity. Otherwise, start again with another random $x$.

This will succeed with probability $1/2$ at each iteration, so you'll get your primitive root rather quickly. Also, you don't need a strongly secure randomness generator here (unless the choice of the primitive root is to be part of some secret).

Take care that there are several primitive $n$-th roots of unity; in your case, there are precisely $n/2$ of them. None of them is more primitive than the others; thus, there is no notion of "*the* primitive root". You find *a* primitive root.

Comment: Note that any finite field has order $q = p^f$ for a prime $p$ and an integer $f$. When $q$ is not prime (i.e. $f > 1$), the finite field of cardinal $q$ is _not_ the ring of integers modulo $q$. I am talking about the field, not the ring.